# Read Internal HDD Data with USB Enclosure

Tags: hard-drive

Is it possible for me to put my internal HDD contain Ubuntu 14.04 into an USB enclosure and connect the USB enclosure with other Ubuntu 14.04 for transferring data from the USB enclosure?

Comment: What's the HDD type? Theoretically, you can.

Answer (score 2):

In short: *as root*: Yes.

You may need to sort out other user's IDs if the two computers don't have the same users defined, but otherwise there shouldn't be any problems.